# Converting an excel application to a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an Excel application with one entry page and one result page. Based on the data entered into the entry page and some static tables present, there are some other worksheets which calculate the values and sum it up later in the results page.

I need to convert this application to a web application and move the whole logic from excel to C#. There will be some UI pages and 1 results page, and the worksheet calculations currently in the excel application will be moved to different C# classes.

Is there any tool for this, or do we have to manually convert every piece of the existing logic to C#? If we have to do it manually, then is there any tool which can help summarize the logic in a text file, so that we don't have to backtrack the whole calculation in Excel to reconstruct the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt a tool could help you do this, and if that tool existed I would expect the resulting C# code to be pretty bad. One of the forces of Excel is that it permits a very flexible programming style; the downside is that the resulting code has very little structure to it, which makes it hard to follow, both for humans and machines. On top of that, the logic can take multiple forms, from an Excel formula to a VBA macro, which complicates matters.

By contrast, C# tends to see the world in terms of classes, which have very specific responsibilities; a program essentially coordinates passing messages between classes so that they can "talk to each other" and collaborate to get the job done.

In that context, at best, I would expect a translation tool to produce a few unpleasant C# procedures. In the end, a spreadsheet (with no VBA) is a set of functions sitting in cells and chained together, there isn't enough structure present to extract meaningful classes/entities that own pieces of functionality.

Furthermore, I would argue that re-thinking this application is an opportunity. A web app can do easily things Excel can't, and vice-versa. Instead of a "word-for-word" close translation, I would focus on retaining the spirit of the application, but design it without thinking too much about the original Excel application.

The benefit of having the Excel application present is that you have a proof of concept already. Instead of trying to convert the code, I would simply track down all the input points that have an influence on other calculated fields (maybe using auditing), list / diagram what influences what (maybe with a simple bubbles- and-arrows diagrams), and attempt to describe in plain English what the user is attempting to do, and what is happening in terms of "entities".  For instance, rather than `=A2*(1-A3)`, I would say "the Product Net Cost is its Cost time (1 - Discount Rate)". And instead of `=SUM(A5:A32)`, I would say "the User wants a summary of the cost of the Products he ordered, which should display the Total Cost of his Order, so that he can have an overview of his order". If you manage to extract a description of your domain with good names and use cases, this will be more helpful to a developer to write the best possible application supporting these requirements, on any platform you may want.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to "convert" the solution. Build it in C# from scratch. They are written in different languages and the UI cannot be reused.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with fabiopagoti. Even if a magical 'converter' would be available, what human would dare to maintain this coded-by-machine application in future updates?

Taking your second question, looking for an alternative helper, [I've found](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/show-formulas-in-cells.php) the **[CTRL]+[`]** key combination that may give you a hand on this: This shortcut displays all formulas in cells, so you can be more confortable you're not missing anything behind. I hope.

PS: To text file? Just apply the shortcut and "print" the sheet to a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Google Docs. It allow to create scripts and use formulas.